# Install Sahara in OpenStack

Tags: 12.04, openstack, hadoop

I have already installed OpenStack following the tutorial from [here](http://ilearnstack.com/2013/04/26/setting-up-a-single-node-openstack-environment/).

I want to install `Apache Hadoop` on `OpenStack` and I saw [here](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/openstack-savanna-fast-hadoop) that first I have to install `DevStack` before I install `Sahara(Savanna)`

My question are: -

- Is it necessary to install `DevStack`
- Is there any other tutorial for Sahara installation except [this](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/sahara/userdoc/installation.guide.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use DevStack. The resource you use for installing OpenStack is 1 year old and seems like it installs Grizzly. Havana was released half a year ago and Icehouse will be released in two weeks.

On the contrary DevStack always installs the latest version of OpenStack, Sahara included.

Comment: Okay I have now installed DevStack.
But it does not have Sahara installed.

Comment: Hurrah... I have installed DevStack again with ENABLED_SERVIES+=,Sahara

Comment: Now I want to install Apache Hadoop on it... Thanks for so much help @dimitryme

Comment: Can you guide me how do I deploy Apache Hadoop over OpenStack?
Here is my question http://askubuntu.com/questions/443263/apache-hadoop-on-openstack