# Apache Hadoop on OpenStack

Tags: 12.04, server, apache2, cloud, openstack

I have deployed `OpenStack`(with Sahara) via cloning `DevStack`. Now I want to deploy `Apache Hadoop` on `OpenStack`.

I have searched a lot and everywhere I find tutorial same as this

http://architects.dzone.com/articles/openstack-savanna-fast-hadoop

I want to ask that is there way to install `Apache Hadoop` via `OpenStack Horizon Dashboard` instead from `Kernel` commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The localrc of you devstack should have Sahara enabled like that:
ENABLED_SERVICES+=sahara

to restart devstack do ./unstack.sh and then ./stack.sh again

If successful, you should see a new 'Sahara' tab in Horizon after log in.

Comment: Yes it is installed. I want to ask that how do I deploy Apache Hadoop on that?

Comment: I saw Apache Hadoop's plugin is installed.
Sorry for my lack of knowledge. I am pretty new to it

Comment: Here is what you should do to launch the cluster:
1. Download the following image:
http://savanna-files.mirantis.com/savanna-icehouse-vanilla-1.2.1-ubuntu-13.10.qcow2
2. Edit 'default' security group: permit access to all ports via TCP
3. Follow these instructions:
http://savanna.readthedocs.org/en/latest/horizon/dashboard.user.guide.html#launching-a-cluster-via-the-savanna-dashboard